# Sinatra server push?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What is the best way to push data from a server written in Sinatra to a client? Think similarly to a chat room, but without Ajax polling every 2500ms.

I know of Juggernaut in Rails, but was curious about Sinatra.

Answer (score 5):

A little googling turned up [this blog post by Marc-André Cournoyer](http://macournoyer.com/blog/2009/06/04/pusher-and-async-with-thin/), which discusses the asynchronous response feature of the Thin web server and includes a link to an async-sinatra library to do just this.  You could also take a look at [orbited-ruby](http://github.com/collin/orbited-ruby/tree/master), a Ruby implementation of the [Orbited](http://orbited.org/) Comet server.  Both of these appear to be pretty new and untested, so you might have to do a little hacking yourselves to get things working correctly for your application.