# Server push in php

Tags: social-networking, push, push-notification

In an app, I am looking forward to implement server push functionality. I have gathered some information about the technology also, but I am little confused that with which language should I prefer for and what else requirement needed(note: this is going to be a social n/w app)?
  I have just finished a project based on php / mysql, so will PHP be a good option or ruby on rail.

So can anybody guide me here. also if any good article before start working on it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a bit unclear if you're asking about creating the push server or client side.

Comment: creation of push server.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is Comet. With PHP, your options are somewhat limited; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php) for details.

Comment: Ok thank you , how would be ruby on rails? i mean overall performance, security purpose.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099051/sinatra-ruby-server-push and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375318/when-will-a-framework-be-available-for-comet